# Best Paid SharePoint Admin Tools

Tags: administration, tools

I would like to know best SharePoint Paid Admin Tools out there. Please NO vendors. As of now I really dont have any hard requirements. Just normal day to day Admin activities. SharePoint hasn't grown as much (in our environment) but I have the budget and like to acquire a tool before they take it out.

Comment: Per the FAQ: "To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions..." http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue of what's best is entirely subjective.  You can go for some larger, more expensive "all-in" admin tools, such as Axceler's ControlPoint ( a personal favourte) and Doc Ave's AvePoint.  These do a lot but as a result demand more system resource than more light weight tools.

You can also get tools for specific jobs, if you find that one particular item is taking a lot of time or resource.

The items I've liked and used in the past are: -
1 Control Point - http://www.axceler.com/products/controlpoint-sharepoint-products/sharepoint-administration/index
2 DocAve 6 - http://www.avepoint.com/docave6/

I'd also suggest browsing SharePoint Reviews to see how people are rating admin products there.

http://www.sharepointreviews.com/sharepoint-administration

Comment: We also use DocAve but the "best" day-to-day admin tool has been the ever so free PowerShell.  Not to be snarky but I literally use PowerShell every single day and only pull up DocAve once or twice per month.  For everything else, the term "best" really will vary based the needs of your organization.

Comment: I heard DocAve leave heavy foot print in the memory unless you dedicate a server for DocAve.

Comment: Agreed with Dave.  PS is great if you're comfortable with command line and there's PLENTY of free scripts out there.  CodePlex and the MS Technet Galleries are great places to start.

Comment: As a ControlPoint customer - avoid completely. We purchased it for two corporate deployments and it's one of the worst planned products I've come across. It feels like no spec was written and features have been bolted on without consideration as to how a site collection admin would utilize them.

Comment: We've been using DocAve extensively and as Donna mentioned it's bit resource hungry but it's a very good tool for day-to-day maintenance of SharePoint. The tool can be easily used by users who have limited knowledge of SharePoint.